# Issue with __reactInternalInstance when using img tag in React component

Tags: image, components, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to display images in my React component. Below is my code:

```
    import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  const posterIMG = "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*AfzFa8zO_dQOmuSHL7bEww.png";
  return(
    <div className="top_nav">
      <div className="nav_menu">
        <nav>
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li className="">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" className="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img id="postertest" src={"/public/images/img.jpg"}  className="img" alt="Profile Image"/>
                <span className=" fa fa-angle-down"/>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className="poster-container nopadding col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-md-8 col-lg-5 pull-lg-7 ">
        <img id="postertest" className='poster' src={posterIMG}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

The code is displaying image but at the same time, throwing console errors . When i remove the image tag, there is no errors in the console.

[image]

Can somebody help me what is happening here?